# How can i minimize performance hit for Coded ui when using nested if statement in test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

Is there a way for me to minimize the performance hit when i'm either running or debugging my coded U.I test. Currently its taking me a long time to run my coded UI test because it takes to long to execute.  I"ve timed it and too long means that for checking if a screen exist and doing an action it takes over 1min plus, so its taking me to long to debug and finish it out.

To give some more background.  These if statements are all inside one test method, where i'm checking for different screens. Its very dynamic but takes to long to run.  I've read i can do ordered test but i didn't think i can create ordered test with these dynamic screens(reason being i dont think ordered test can act as if statements to account for dynamic dialog and screens) and plus i think its too late in the process to go to that architecture.

I've tried the following playback settings with little or no improvements.

Here are my current playback settings

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
        //Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.None;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.MaximumRetryCount = 10;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ShouldSearchFailFast = false;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions = 1000;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 2000;
```

None of these setting have helped either turning off smart options.

I could have sworn that i've read somewhere that if i replace my if statements

with try catch that this would help, but i maybe totally wrong since i'm just grabbing at straws to try to atleast increase performance by 40% or so.

Would anyone have any tips or tricks when dealing with ifs statements that you had to code in your coded ui code.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Generating exceptions to control flow probably isn't the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your if statements are of a kind:

```
if (uTtestControl.exists)
{
do something
}
```

if that's the case - your delays are a result of codedui searching for the control - a time costly operation - especially when searching for a control that doesn't exists.

there are a number of ways to handle this - if my guess is in the ball park - please confirm and i'll detail the options.

**Updtae:**

1. the main reason for delay is the MaximumRetryCount =10. in addition try the following settings:

   ```
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.MaximumRetryCount = 3;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions = 100;
   Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 15000;
   ```

   2. when waiting for control to exists use the:

      ```
      uiTtestControl.WaitForControlExist(5000)
      ```

this will tell the playback to search for the control for a max of 5 sec.

3. in addition - you should reduce the  Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout before searching for a control that you know might not exists:

   ```
         var defaultTimeout = Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout;
         Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 5000;
   ```

and after you finish searching return it to the default value:

```
 Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = defaultTimeout;
```

this should do the trick

Comment: That is correct, i'm waiting for a TestControl to exists

Comment: Hi barakcaf, thanks for the reply.  I tried the solution but it didn't speed up my program. This is my first major project in Coded UI. Knowing this i think i might of messed up on creating my coded UI maps or accounting for certain things.

Comment: Hi @barakcaf, thanks for the reply.  I tried the solution but it didn't speed up my program. This is my first major project in Coded UI. Knowing this i think i might of messed up on creating my coded UI maps or accounting for certain things.
One problem is accounting for screens that are changing. To Account for this i changed alot of the UI maps to not use the Parent screen name because the title of the pages werent constant if that makes sense.  This cause me to add specific objects on the UI map. It works but its very slow i mean slower then a turtle of i had one. Have you worked on a

Comment: such a project where screens are constantly changing. How can i correctly account for this and make the coded UI search objects alot faster.  Example On some of my browser screens I had to use the back button since the elements inside the page are different.  I remember reading that you can pass your browser from method to method or something like that, I dont think i'm leveraging this or the better statement maybe that i didn't correctly leverage this.

Comment: you can pass your browser between methods just like you pass any other c# object, but you cannot pass it between different test cases.